# Continuous Analogue for Capital Pi "production" as Integral is to Capital Sigma Summation?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

This is a strange question, but in my calculus class we have recently been learning about the definitions and properties of summations and how they relate to integrals. Namely, how integration may be considered a continuous analogue for summation, specified in the following relation:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{i=1}f(x_i^*)\Delta x=\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

I am curious about a continuous equivalent for a capital-pi product series, as capital sigma is to the traditional integral. Namely,

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i^*)\Delta x=?$$

Of course, $\displaystyle\prod^n_{i=1}n = n!$ , making the continuous equivalent $\Gamma(x+1)$. But I was curious if there is a more general operation or approach to this.

Edit: I know the gamma function is not continuous as it is not defined for the negative integers, but I am using continuous in this question as the opposite of discrete. Let me know if there is more appropriate terminology I should use.

Comment: The $\Delta x$ can't really go there, as written that limit is just going to be zero. We don't need a separate theory for products because we can just take logarithms to reduce to sums as we always do with logarithms.

Comment: The right analog would be more like $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i^*)^{\Delta x}$. See [product integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral#Type_II:_geometric_integral)

Comment: as @QiaochuYuan mentioned the limit will just be zero as we have $\Delta x^n$. If you are curious about turning it into a summation notice that $$\ln \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln (a_n)$$